# Modificar contenido de un tupla en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo la siguiente `tupla`, lo que quiero hacer es sumar a cada primer elemento +1, es decir, el primer elemento 15 pase a ser 16, el 258 a 259 y así sucesivamente. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo? Muchas gracias de antemano.

> [(15, 0.12143221), (258, 0.07235707), (208, 0.06686923), (253,
>   0.056732856), (84, 0.052190553), (185, 0.047896527), (169, 0.03725162), (7, 0.033070035), (153, 0.029168405), (314, 0.028492954)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los objetos `float` son  objetos inmutables, por lo que no se puede modificar su valor una vez instanciado. Para cambiar el valor del primer índice de la tupla tendrías que asignar un nuevo objeto `float` a ese índice.

El problema es que las tuplas son objetos inmutables también en Python. Esto significa que no podrás asignar nuevos objetos a indices ya existentes ni eliminar o agregar uno nuevo.

`Tupla de objetos inmutables`

```
>>> t = (1, 2, 3)
>>> t[0] += 1     # Al ser int inmutable esto implica asignación

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

`Tupla de objetos inmutables`

```
>>> t = ([1], [2], [3])
>>> t[0] += [13]        # Podemos modificar un objeto mutable, no se resigna
>>> t
([1, 13], [2], [3])


>>> t = ([1], [2], [3])
>>> t[0] = [13]         # En este caso reasignamos

TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

Una tupla en si misma es inmutable, pero puede contener objetos mutables que si pueden ser modificados, este no es el caso.

Por lo tanto, tendrás que crear nuevas tuplas con los valores ya modificados, por ejemplo puedes crear una nueva lista usando listas por compresión:

```
t = [(15, 0.12143221), (258, 0.07235707), (208, 0.06686923),
     (253, 0.056732856), (84, 0.052190553), (185, 0.047896527),
     (169, 0.03725162), (7, 0.033070035), (153, 0.029168405),
     (314, 0.028492954)
     ]
t = [(a + 1, b) for a, b in t]
```

El el caso de que tengamos tuplas de distinto tamaño o con muchos más elementos, una forma general es:

```
t = [(a + 1, *b) for a, *b in t]
```

Si se quiere modificar cualquier índice, podemos recurrir a rebanado, por ejemplo, sumando 1 al tercer elemento de cada tupla:

```
>>> t = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 4), (7, 8, 9, 10)]
>>> t = [(*st[:2], st[2] + 1, *st[3:]) for st in t]
[(1, 2, 4), (4, 5, 5), (7, 8, 10, 10)]
```

Obviamente este tipo de operaciones son ineficientes. Si vas a realizar operaciones de este tipo a menudo, evita usar tuplas y usa listas, que a diferencia de las primeras son mutables:

```
t = [(15, 0.12143221), (258, 0.07235707), (208, 0.06686923),
     (253, 0.056732856), (84, 0.052190553), (185, 0.047896527),
     (169, 0.03725162), (7, 0.033070035), (153, 0.029168405),
     (314, 0.028492954)
     ]

t = list(map(list, t))
```

Ahora puedes modificar sin problemas el objeto asociado a cada índice:

```
for p in t:
    p[0] += 1
```

> ```
> >>> t
>
> [[16, 0.12143221],
>  [259, 0.07235707],
>  [209, 0.06686923],
>  [254, 0.056732856],
>  [85, 0.052190553],
>  [186, 0.047896527],
>  [170, 0.03725162],
>  [8, 0.033070035],
>  [154, 0.029168405],
>  [315, 0.028492954]]
> ```

---

> - Son objetos/tipos inmutables:
>
>   `int`, `float`, `complex`, `str`, `bytes`, `tuple`, `frozenset` y `bool`
> - Son objetos/tipos mutables:
>
>   `list`, `set`, `dict` y `bytearray`

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación, muy útil. me sirvió usando la lista por comprensión